# Perl color specifiers with redirected output

Tags: linux, perl, bash

I have a Perl script that uses `Term::ANSIColor`. It used to be the case that if I redirect the output to a file `> file.txt` then the file contains just the text, and not the color codes `^[[0m`

Something changed on my machine, Ubuntu 10.04, such that redirected output includes these special characters that specify color.

Any idea how to fix this? Can I detect output redirection from inside the perl script and skip the color part?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can test whether you're running interactively using the [IO::Interactive](http://search.cpan.org/~bdfoy/IO-Interactive-0.0.6/lib/IO/Interactive.pm) package:

```
use IO::Interactive qw(is_interactive);

if (is_interactive())
{
    # show some fancy color
}
```

The rationale behind using IO::Interactive (instead of just testing if `STDIN` is a tty with the `-t` operator) is extensively [explained by Damian Conway](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=472045).

Comment: For a quick little script, though, -t STDIN is perfectly acceptable. I use that for any one-offs I want colorized.

Comment: @zostay I wasn't successful at preventing colors by checking -t STDIN. My script is run as `./Script.prl > file.txt`. However checking -t STDOUT worked correctly

Comment: @Mikhail: in that case you'd probably want to test `STDOUT` instead of `STDIN`.

Comment: @Mikhail, that's what I actually meant. I was confused by the STDIN comment above. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @zostay: Agreed, generally speaking, testing `STDIN` or `STDOUT` is enough.